# Getting parameter in ASM from C call

Tags: c, nasm

I call an asm function from a C program, then I try to call another C function and give new parameters, but the second function received the parameters of asm. Here are the 3 files.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ac.h"

int main (int argc,char **argv)
{
    char * s = _pusher(115,9);
    fprintf(stdout,"From pusher '%s'\n",s);
    free(s);
    return EXIT_SUCESS;
}
```

File ac.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ac.h"

char * _aff(int a,int b)
{
    char * s;
    fprintf(stdout,"In aff(%d,%d)\n",a,b);
    asprintf(&s,"v = %d - %d",a,b);

    return s;
 }
```

File aa.asm

```
[CPU x64]
[BITS 64]

extern _aff
global _pusher

[SECTION .text]
_pusher:
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp

    push 123  ;seems no effect
    push 321  ;seems no effect

    call _aff

    add rsp,24
    mov rsp,rbp
    pop rbp
    ret

[SECTION .data]
[SECTION .bss]
```

When I execute, I get this output:

```
In aff(115,9)
From pusher : 'v = 115 - 9'
```

But I was expecting

```
In aff(123,321)
From pusher : 'v = 123 - 321'
```

How do I pass my own new parameters? The final goal is to take in `_pusher a char **` and call `aff` like this:

```
_aff(char *param,...) and use VA_LIST inside so pusher should be call like this
_pusher(int count,char **tbl)
```

Comment: Read the ABI of your platform and pass arguments as expected.

Comment: the strange thing is that those parameter send from main are going streight to _aff. I thought mov rbp,rsp made my new stack

Comment: Don't just repeat what you already clarified in the question. If you don't understand my comment, search for "ABI".

Comment: I don't understand your comment and not because of ABI. I am using fedora 23 x64 and i read this to write the code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI is probably the most relevant section. You really need to get the official fedora ABI.

Comment: [64-bit System V Linux calling convention](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) passes first 6 parameters (that can be represented in 8 bytes) in registers (rather than the stack). _RDI_ and _RSI_ are the first two parameters.

Comment: Thanks Micheal Petch and user3386109 that was clear.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add SOLVED to your question title. If you want to share a solution, do so by writing an actual answer in the space below that is provided for that purpose. If you don't want to share your solution, feel free to delete this question.

Comment: Ok, sorry i am new here did not know. I will send the solution a bit later

Answer (score 1):

The OP noticed that the parameters he was passing to his assembly-language function weren't being processed.

@Olaf noted that the OP wasn't using the correct ABI (Application Binary Interface - the definition of how to call functions on a platform) for his environment - he was using a (much) older one described in Wikipedia.

@Michael Petch clarified by stating that for x64 development, instead of `PUSH`ing the values onto the stack (an x86 convention), he should load them into the first two expected registers: `RDI` and `RSI`

Answer (score 0):

I just realise I forgot to post the working code, after 6 month oops.
so the asm function will receive a char ** and will formate it to send to redis.

hope this code will be usefull for others.

```
redisReply * _pusher(redisContext *c, int count, char **args);
```

then _pusher will call redisCommand(c,"%s %s ...",args[0],...,args[count-1]) :

```
[CPU x64]                                                             
[BITS                                                          
extern redisCommand
global _pusher   

[SECTION.text]                                                                
_pusher:
push rbp
mov rbp,rsp

mov rax,rsi
cmp rax,1  
je arg_1

cmp rax,2
je arg_2 

cmp rax,3
je arg_3 

cmp rax,4
je arg_4

cmp rax,5
jge arg_more 

arg_1:                                                         
sub rsp,0x3
mov byte [rbp - 0x3],0x25
mov byte [rbp - 0x2],0x73                                     
mov byte [rbp - 0x1],0x0                                     

mov rax,rdi                                                 
mov rdi,rdx                                                 
mov rdx,[rdi]                                                 
lea rsi,[rbp - 0x3]                                      
mov rdi,rax                                                 
jmp debut_appel                                                 

arg_2:                                                         
sub rsp,0x6                                                 
mov byte [rbp - 0x6],0x25                                     
mov byte [rbp - 0x5],0x73                                     
mov byte [rbp - 0x4],0x20                                     
mov byte [rbp - 0x3],0x25                                     
mov byte [rbp - 0x2],0x73                                     
mov byte [rbp - 0x1],0x0                                     

mov rax,rdi                                                 
mov rdi,rdx                                                 
mov rdx,[rdi]                                                 
mov rcx,[rdi + 0x8]                                      
lea rsi,[rbp - 0x6]                                      
mov rdi,rax                                                 
jmp debut_appel 

arg_3:
sub rsp,0x9
mov byte [rbp - 0x9],0x25
mov byte [rbp - 0x8],0x73
mov byte [rbp - 0x7],0x20
mov byte [rbp - 0x6],0x25
mov byte [rbp - 0x5],0x73
mov byte [rbp - 0x4],0x20
mov byte [rbp - 0x3],0x25
mov byte [rbp - 0x2],0x73
mov byte [rbp - 0x1],0x0

mov rax,rdi
mov rdi,rdx
mov rdx,[rdi]
mov rcx,[rdi + 0x8]
mov r8, [rdi + 0x10]
lea rsi,[rbp - 0x9]
mov rdi,rax
jmp debut_appel

arg_4:
sub rsp,0xc
mov byte [rbp - 0xc],0x25
mov byte [rbp - 0xb],0x73
mov byte [rbp - 0xa],0x20
mov byte [rbp - 0x9],0x25
mov byte [rbp - 0x8],0x73
mov byte [rbp - 0x7],0x20
mov byte [rbp - 0x6],0x25
mov byte [rbp - 0x5],0x73
mov byte [rbp - 0x4],0x20
mov byte [rbp - 0x3],0x25
mov byte [rbp - 0x2],0x73
mov byte [rbp - 0x1],0x0

mov rax,rdi
mov rdi,rdx
mov rdx,[rdi]
mov rcx,[rdi + 0x8]
mov r8, [rdi + 0x10]
mov r9, [rdi + 0x18]
lea rsi,[rbp - 0xc]
mov rdi,rax
jmp debut_appel

arg_more:
mov r8,rdi                                         
mov rdi,rdx
mov rcx,rax
sub rcx,5
lea rax, [rcx * 3]
add rax, 0xf

sub rsp,rax
mov rdx,rbp
sub rdx,rax
lea rsi,[rdx]

mov byte [rbp - 0xc],0x25
mov byte [rbp - 0xb],0x73
mov byte [rbp - 0xa],0x20
mov byte [rbp - 0x9],0x25
mov byte [rbp - 0x8],0x73
mov byte [rbp - 0x7],0x20
mov byte [rbp - 0x6],0x25
mov byte [rbp - 0x5],0x73
mov byte [rbp - 0x4],0x20
mov byte [rbp - 0x3],0x25
mov byte [rbp - 0x2],0x73
mov byte [rbp - 0x1],0x0


;debut de boucle
loop_start:
    mov byte [rdx],0x25
    mov byte [rdx + 1],0x73
    mov byte [rdx + 2],0x20
    add rdx,0x3

    lea rax , [rcx * 0x8]
    mov rbx,[rdi + rax + 0x20]
    push rbx
```